# VxWorks 6.8 Image Project Not Compiling

Tags: vxworks

I am using Wind River Workbench 3.3 and VxWorks 6.8.  When using building from the command line everything works, but when I attempt to build within Workbench I get errors.  In attempting to track it down, I have determined that the same problem occurs when creating a new VxWorks Image Project using our board support package and the gnu tool chain.

I created a new project and attempt to build it in the default_romCompress build spec.  I get the following errors.

```
romInit.o: In function `delay_100us':
C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/config/mrim/romInit.s:649: undefined reference to `romStart'
C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/config/mrim/romInit.s:650: undefined reference to `romStart'
make.exe[1]: *** [vxWorks_romCompress] Error 1
rm ipcom_ipdomain
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test/default_romCompress'
C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin\make.exe: *** [target_vxWorks] Error 2
Build Failed in Project 'Test' (Process Exit Value was 2):   2014-01-14 17:22:11   (Elapsed Time: 00:06)
```

the symbol romStart is defined in romStart.c, which is part of the project.  When I attempt to compile just romStart.c I get the following output.

```
Build Started in Project 'Test':   2014-01-15 08:57:25
Generation of makefiles started.
Generation of makefiles finished (Elapsed Time: 00:00).
Platform: Wind River VxWorks 6.8
Command: make BUILD_SPEC=default_romCompress DEBUG_MODE=0 TRACE=1 default_romCompress/romStart.o
Working Directory: D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test'
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test/default_romCompress'
ccppc -c -DCPU_VARIANT=_ppc860 -g -msoft-float -mstrict-align -ansi -fno-builtin -Wall -D_VSB_CONFIG_FILE=\"C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/lib/h/config/vsbConfig.h\" -mcpu=860 -I.. -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/config/mrim -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/h -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/config/comps/src -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/h/wrn/coreip -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/src/drv -DCPU=PPC32 -DTOOL_FAMILY=gnu -DTOOL=sfgnu -DPRJ_BUILD -D_WRS_KERNEL -IC:/WindRiver/components/windml-5.3/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/webservices-1.7/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/webcli-4.8/target/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/opc-3.2/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/dcom-2.3/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/windml-5.3/osconfig/vxworks/src -IC:/WindRiver/components/ip_net2-6.8/osconfig/vxworks/src -IC:/WindRiver/components/windml-5.3/osconfig/vxworks/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/ip_net2-6.8/osconfig/vxworks/h -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/src/hwif -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/src/hwif/h @./ipcom_ipdomain -DIP_PORT_VXWORKS=68 -DINET -UCPU -DCPU=PPC860 -I. -MD  -fvolatile -G8 -msdata=eabi -DROM_COMPRESS -DRAM_DATA_ADRS=0x00e00000 -DRAM_DST_ADRS=0x00010000 C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/config/comps/src/romStart.c -o romStart.o
ccppc: @./ipcom_ipdomain: No such file or directory
make.exe[2]: *** [romStart.o] Error 1
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test/default_romCompress'
make.exe[1]: *** [compile_romStart.o] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test'
C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin\make.exe: *** [default_romCompress/romStart.o] Error 2
Build Failed in Project 'Test' (Process Exit Value was 2):   2014-01-15 08:57:26   (Elapsed Time: 00:01)
```

However, if I attempt to compile romStart.c a second time, then it succeeds

If I again try to build the project (not clean and not rebuild), then it fails again with the following output.

```
Build Started in Project 'Test':   2014-01-15 08:58:36
Generation of makefiles started.
Generation of makefiles finished (Elapsed Time: 00:00).
Platform: Wind River VxWorks 6.8
Command: make BUILD_SPEC=default_romCompress DEBUG_MODE=0 TRACE=1
Working Directory: D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test
building default vxWorks image of D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test/default_romCompress'
cp vxWorks vxWorks.o
true  vxWorks.o
objcopyppc -O binary --binary-without-bss vxWorks.o tmp.bin
VX_CPU_FAMILY=ppc C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/host/x86-win32/bin/deflate < tmp.bin > tmp.Z
Deflation: 53.98%
VX_CPU_FAMILY=ppc C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/host/x86-win32/bin/binToAsm tmp.Z > vxWorks.Z.s
ccppc -c -DCPU_VARIANT=_ppc860 -g -msoft-float -mstrict-align -ansi -fno-builtin -xassembler-with-cpp -D_VSB_CONFIG_FILE=\"C:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/lib/h/config/vsbConfig.h\" -mcpu=860 -I.. -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/config/mrim -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/h -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/config/comps/src -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/h/wrn/coreip -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/src/drv -DCPU=PPC32 -DTOOL_FAMILY=gnu -DTOOL=sfgnu -DPRJ_BUILD -D_WRS_KERNEL -IC:/WindRiver/components/windml-5.3/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/webservices-1.7/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/webcli-4.8/target/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/opc-3.2/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/dcom-2.3/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/windml-5.3/osconfig/vxworks/src -IC:/WindRiver/components/ip_net2-6.8/osconfig/vxworks/src -IC:/WindRiver/components/windml-5.3/osconfig/vxworks/h -IC:/WindRiver/components/ip_net2-6.8/osconfig/vxworks/h -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/src/hwif -IC:/WindRiver/vxworks-6.8/target/src/hwif/h @./ipcom_ipdomain -DIP_PORT_VXWORKS=68 -DINET -UCPU -DCPU=PPC860 -I. -MD vxWorks.Z.s -o vxWorks.Z.o
ccppc: @./ipcom_ipdomain: No such file or directory
make.exe[1]: *** [vxWorks_romCompress] Error 1
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `D:/WindRiverWorkbench/Test/default_romCompress'
C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin\make.exe: *** [target_vxWorks] Error 2
Build Failed in Project 'Test' (Process Exit Value was 2):   2014-01-15 08:58:37   (Elapsed Time: 00:01)
```

Can anyone suggest how I might go about fixing these problems?